# Reducing Inelastic Electron-Proton's Scattering Cross Section to Rosenbluth's Formula

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, nuclear-physics, scattering-cross-section, protons

I'm currently studying electron-proton scattering from Halzen & Martin's book (Quarks & Leptons : An Introductory Course in Modern Particle Physics). I found that the cross section for the inelastic version of e-p scattering is given by

$$\frac{d\sigma}{dE'd\Omega}=\frac{\alpha^2}{4E^2\sin^4(\theta/2)}\left(W_2(\nu,q^2)\cos^2\frac{\theta}{2}+2W_1(\nu,q^2)\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$$

where $W_2$ is the electromagnetic structure function and $W_1$ is the magnetic structure function. How can we reduce this cross section to the Rosenbluth's formula for elastic e-p scattering?

$$\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}=\frac{\alpha^2}{4E^2\sin^4(\theta/2)}\frac{E'}{E}\left(\frac{G_E^2+\tau G_M^2}{1+\tau}\cos^2\frac{\theta}{2}+2\tau G_M^2\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$$

Is it as simple as choosing the $W_1$ and $W_2$?